# IIS7 web site not working properly after file sharing on wwwroot

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, iis-7

I recently tried to add a file share on wwwroot to easily be able to deply some files from a different copmuter on the network. I added the share with full access to my user, but only me. After I had copied over the files, I removed the share, but now the web sites does not work propelry anymore. I get unauthirized-messages when I try to access the web pages. It is set up with anonomous access enabled in IIS, and security on folder is set up with read/execute access for Everybody, but it still does not work properly. I tried to remove and add each application under wwwroot in IIS, and that worked for some, but not all.

Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the user "network service" back into the permission set. This is a service account and not a member of the Everyone group. By default IIS runs under the Network Service account unless you manually change the user under the Application Pool setting.

Comment: I found out a fix for it. The anonymous user was set up to be IUSR, and I changed it to use the application pool user instead (which is "Network Service" as you say) . I don't know why this was so, or even why it works now, but it works, so hurray!..